# How do I calculate a normal?

Tags: java, math, vector, normalization

Okay, so say I got a rectangle (This is all 2d) made from Thing A's x,y,width and height. How would I calculate it's normal?

Comment: What do you mean by a normal of a rectangle?

Comment: I don't know, maybe like which way it's facing?

Comment: I need to know which way it's facing so I can reflect stuff off it.

Comment: @CyanPrime In 2d, there's only one way a rectangle can be facing, okay, maybe two: up and down. I don't think that's what you want. What do you need this normal for then?

Comment: @CyanPrime, so what you actually have is a line?

Comment: @CyanPrime: "Which way is this rectangle facing?" doesn't make any sense in 2D...

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it would just be a line?

Comment: He means a normal from a line, not a normal from a rectangle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cyan,

You are NOT looking for the normal as defined by the cross product or 3 dimensions. One minute and I will explain..

**EDIT:**

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454661/reflection-how-do-i-do-it/5455666#5455666), it is obvious that what you are looking for is simply a vector perpendicular to a line. Not a vector perpendicular to a plane.

To mathematically evaluate

```
R = A - 2<A, N> N
```

You must first have a firm understanding of a [Euclidean Vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector).

Given a vector A (your angle of incidence):

```
A = <ax, ay>
```

Given the vector B (which represents a vector of the wall being bounced off of):

```
B = <bx, by>
```

The normal (perpendicular) to this vector is simply rotated 90 degrees. Mathematically:

```
N = <nx, ny> = <-bx, by>
```

Therefore R =

```
R = A - 2<A, N> N = ...
```

Lets first evaluate the Dot Product

```
<A, N> = ax*nx + ay*ny = ax*(-bx) + ay*by = ay*by - ax*bx
```

Then:

```
R = <ax, ay> - 2*(ay*by - ax*bx) * N
  = <ax, by> - <2*(ay*by - ax*bx)*nx, 2*(ay*by - ax*bx)*ny>
  = <ax, by> - <2*(ay*by - ax*bx)*(-bx), 2*(ay*by - ax*bx)*(by)>
  = < ax + 2*bx*(ay*by - ax*bx), ay - 2*by*(ay*by - ax*bx) >
```

So all you need to do is determine a vector representing the wall you are bouncing off of (which is B), and your incident Vector (which is A).

**EDIT** (because of comment):

You really ought to spend time reviewing the link I posted to Euclidean vectors...

The basic idea is that you define an arbitrary mathematical origin. (Say for example, and the bottom of your wall). A vector representing your wall is then just an arrow, from the top to the bottom (or the bottom to the top). With the origin described at the base, this arrow will point 0 units in the x direction, but 100 units in the y direction. Therefore your vector for the wall (B) is just:

```
B = < 0, 100 >
```

(Note that the width of your wall is unimportant - it would bounce the same with a wall 1px thick, 50 px thick, or 100px thick).

But you'll want to normalize this vector so it has unit magnitude (length of 1). So the vector becomes:

```
B = <0, 1>
```

This follows from:

```
Vector length = sqrt( bx^2 + by^2 ) = sqrt( 0^2 + 1^2 ) = 1
```

N is then:

```
N = <1, 0>  // for the left hand side wall
N = <-1, 0> // for the right hand side wall
```

Comment: Sorry about the late reply, I fell asleep. But I'm wondering something. B = <bx, by>
Now how would I get 1 number like that from a line? Let's say my line is (50, 0) and (50, 100) making it 1px wide, and 100px tall, and a normal of 90 (i think?) how do I turn this wall into one vector for B?

Comment: @CyanPrime: See my post. Please review the vector mathematics I posted a link to.

Comment: @J T - I think your eq. 'N = <nx, ny> = <-bx, by>' should actually be <-by, bx>?

Comment: @ysap: You are correct for a a 90 degree clockwise rotation. But I don't think it matters all that much in this case. :)

Answer (score 2):

If by "normal" you mean a perpendicular vector, take a look at the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product): for the vectors

```
<a1, a2, a3>
```

and

```
<b1, b2, b3>
```

the cross product is

```
<a2 * b3 - b2 * a3, a1 * b3 - b1 * a3, a1 * b2 - b1 * a2>
```

... but "normal" in pure 2D doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Cross product is for coordinates in 3 dimensional space.

Comment: @Mahesh: Yeah, I assumed this is what the OP meant, since the normal to a 2D rectangle is in 3D.

Comment: Can I get this answer in 2d? Please?

Comment: Using this approach, the normal of every rectangle is (0,0,1).

Comment: <a2 * 1 - b2 * 1, a1 * 1 - b1 * 1, a1 * b2 - b1 * a2>

Would that work for 2d?

Comment: @CyanPrime: It *works* for 2D (and as others pointed out, it gives you some multiple of `<0, 0, 1>`), but the answer is in 3D by definition...

Comment: I'm trying to get the normal this guy is talking about for reflection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454661/reflection-how-do-i-do-it/5455666#5455666

"

Comment: @CyanPrime By definition, a normal is perpendicular to the object it is calculated from. Therefore the normal of a `k` dimensional object is a vector in at least `k+1` dimensions. You can calculate the normal of a line in 2d or a rectangle in 3d but not the normal of a rectangle in 2d. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I believe @CyanPrime wants the perpendicular line to each side of the rectangle (though if it is for reflection I am not sure why you would not want the angle of reflection instead of always reflecting to 90 degrees)

Comment: @CyanPrime In this case you need the normal of an edge of the rectangle. Since your rectangles are always aligned with your coordinates, your normals will be (0,1), (0,-1), (1,0) or (-1,0) depending on whether it's the top, left, bottom or right edge.

Answer (score 1):

Go google 'Cross Product'. [(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)

Take the vectors that define the edges of your rectangle as the vectors you are trying to cross.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. A rectangle has two possible normals:

[image]

In the plane it has 4 normals:

[image]

Comment: While the drawing is pretty, a rectangle has an infinite amount of normals.

Comment: @Blindy: Whoooops I upvoted your comment accidentally. :( No, it doesn't have an infinite number of normals... vectors are just directions, not points. :\

Answer (score 0):

Well if your rectangle is on the XY plane, then a normal is (0,0,1). No need for algebra!

Comment: @Andrew: Note that @Blindy said "**a** normal is (0,0,1)", not "*the* normal".

Comment: What if it's rotated to like a 60 degree angle? I'm hoping for a formula I can code in and make it so stuff will bounce off the rect no matter the angle.

Comment: @Mehrdad, precisely. @CyanPrime, Mehrdad already gave you the general formula. I don't think you understand what exactly a normal is.

Answer (score 0):

The normal to the whole rectangle will be perpendicular to the plane of the rectangle (along the third dimension).

If you mean normal to a *side* of the rectangle (but in the same plane as the rectangle), then you can calculate the slopes of the sides, and the slope of the normal will be negative reciprocal of the slope of the side to which it is normal.  (Or undefined if the slope of the side is zero.)  If you want to put this normal on the rectangle, the midpoint of the side is a good place for it.

Answer (score 0):

What cyanprime is looking for is a normal of 1 line in 2D space.

That normal has to fulfill the following condition:

m_line * m_normal = -1

whereas m_line is the magnitude of the line and m_normal is the magnitude of the normal.

=> m_normal = -1 / m_line

Obviously produces errors if m_line = 0. So you will want to treat that case specially.

If m_line is not 0, you get your 2D-Vector

normal_vector = (1, m_normal)

Answer (score 0):

A normal in 2D is the vector that did 90 degrees in the object, in the opposite direction of the object that should hit it comes.

There's fixed values for those normals, and those are:

West (1, 0); 
East (-1, 0); 
North (0, -1); 
South (0, 1);