# How to reflect a rayCast in libGDX?

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d, trigonometry

`world.rayCast` in `libGDX` provides back a fixture it hit, a point where it hit, a normal for the surface it hit,and a fraction. How can I calculate the reflection direction for a new `rayCast` from the hit point?

PS:I am trying to reflect the ray

THANK YOU

Comment: You have the normal of the hit so you can use that to work out the reflection. I found this which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5455666/2979092

Comment: came across that formula..thank you ill try it